# Logic in Stored Procedure, Strongly Typed dataAccess or web services level

Tags: c#, asp.net, database, web-services, architecture

I am in process in developing my first enterprise level application, but confused with some key factors,

Right now my flow of application to get data is,

- Stored Procedure - Do Inner Joins, and just get the data as it is in tables and pass to strongly TDS
- Strongly Typed DataSet - Pass data as is it to web services which called it
- web services - Make changes to data here to return it back to application layer

Is this right way ? or should we try as much as possible to put right format data in DB, so web services won't need to change it to a certain format. e.g. Date Column to a specified format, or we store user SID in db and then in web services, call active Directory to get user's display name and so on..

Please also guide me where can I read about such architecture examples to learn best practices.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, instead of making changes directly in the web services layer, I would do so in another layer called business layer. The web services layer would only be a proxy to the external world. I would do so because if you wish to expose your logic in any other way, for instance, REST APIs, you would only have to put this extra layer on the top of the business layer.

So you would have something like this:

1. Store Procedure layer
2. Strongly Typed Dataset layer
3. Business layer - where all the logic sorting out your data would be
4. Web services layer. Or another one, for instance REST API layer.

In another subject, instead of using Datasets, I would use NHibernate, Entity Framework or IBatis.NET to handle your persistence layer.